# How to detect container outside click

Tags: javascript

I have a International country code selector code for my website but the problem I'm facing is that I want to hide the dropdown menu when anyone clicks outside the container, I have already written the code for this feature but the bug I'm facing right now is that It closes the dropdown menu when anyone clicks inside of the container, not the outside. it's doing the exact opposite.

I want to hide the menu when clicked outside.

Please check out my Highlighted code -

Please suggest me some modification.

I have done little modification in my code, please check out below.

```js
/********** Hide the menu when clicked outside ***********/

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (container.contains(event.target)) {
    container.classList.remove('show');
  }
});

/********** Hide the menu when clicked outside ***********/


// Cache the elements
  const xbutton = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector .telcode');
  const container = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector .container');
  const input = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector input');
  const list = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector .list');
  
  // Add event listeners to the button, input, and list
  // We use a process called "event delegation" on the list
  // to catch events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM
  // https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/
  xbutton.addEventListener('click', handleButton);
  input.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
  list.addEventListener('click', handleListClick);
  document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);
  
  // Handles the document click - it checks to see if the clicked
  // part of the document has a parent element which is either
  // `null` or is the HTML element, and then closes the container
  // if it's open
  function handleDocumentClick(e) {
    const { parentElement } = e.target;
  }

  
  // All of the data held as objects within an array
  const data = [
    { name: 'Afganistan', code: '69', flag: 'afg' },
    { name: 'Barbados', code: '1-246', flag: 'brb' },
    { name: 'Bolivia', code: '591', flag: 'bol' },
    { name: 'Cuba', code: '53', flag: 'cub' },
    { name: 'Fiji', code: '679', flag: 'fji' },
  ];
  
  // Filters the data based on the characters
  // at the start of the provided name
  function filterData(data, value) {
    return data.filter(obj => {
      return (
        obj.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
        || obj.code.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
  }
  
  // Create a series of list items based on the
  // data passed to it
  function createListHtml(data) {
    return data.map(obj => {
      const { name, code, flag } = obj;
      return `
        <li
          class="item"
          data-name="${name}"
          data-code="${code}"
          data-flag="${flag}"
        >
          <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
          <div class="name">${name} (+${code})</div>
        </li>
      `;
    }).join('');
  }
  
  // Toggle the container on/off
  function handleButton() {
    container.classList.toggle('show');
  }
  
  // No data available list item
  function createNoDataHtml() {
    return '<li class="nodata">No data available</li>';
  }
  
  // When the input is changed filter the data
  // according to the current value, and then
  // create some list items using that filtered data
  function handleInput(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value) {
      const filtered = filterData(data, value);
      if (filtered.length) {
        list.innerHTML = createListHtml(filtered);
      } else {
        list.innerHTML = createNoDataHtml();
      }
    } else {
      list.innerHTML = createListHtml(data);
    }
  }
  
  // Create some button HTML
  function createButtonHtml(code, flag) {
    return `
      <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
      <div class="code">+${code}</div>
    `;
  }
  
  // Updates the selected list by removing the `selected`
  // class from all items, and then adding one to the clicked
  // item
  function updateSelected(list, item) {
    const items = list.querySelectorAll('.item');
    items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('selected'));
    item.classList.add('selected');
  }
  
  // When an item is clicked, grab the relevant data
  // attributes, create the new button HTML, and then 
  // close the container
  function handleListClick(e) {
    const item = e.target.closest('li') || e.target;
    if (item.classList.contains('item')) {
      const { code, flag } = item.dataset;
      xbutton.innerHTML = createButtonHtml(code, flag);
      updateSelected(list, item);
      container.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
  
  list.innerHTML = createListHtml(data);
```

```css
.country-code-selector .telcode {
       margin-bottom: 1em;
       display: flex;
  }
  .country-code-selector .telcode div.code, .item div.name {
       margin-left: 0.25em;
  }
  .country-code-selector .container {
       display: none;
       border: 1px solid grey;
  }
  .country-code-selector .show {
       display: block;
  }
  .country-code-selector .list {
       height: 100px;
       list-style: none;
       margin: 1em 0 0 0;
       padding: 0;
       overflow-y: scroll;
       border: 1px soldi darkgray;
  }
  .country-code-selector .item {
       display: flex;
       padding: 0.25em;
       border: 1px solid lightgray;
  }
  .country-code-selector .item:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
  }
  .country-code-selector .item:hover, .item.selected {
       background-color: lightyellow;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="country-code-selector">
  <button type="button" class="telcode">Tel code</button>
  <section class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for country" />
    <ul class="list"></ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your full code. That includes the HTML, click handler JS for the dropdown etc.

Comment: What is `container`?

Comment: `if (!container.contains(event.target)) {` This should work!

Comment: The answers and the duplicate question are all too confusing. All you got to do is make use of `e.stopPropagation()` correctly
https://jsbin.com/lurikis

Comment: if I add the ! before container then my click button is not working, please check my JS snippet